# Bad Parcelable exception

Tags: java, android

first of all I must say I´ve been searching for an answer to my problem here at this site and I found several topics regarding this exception but after all the threads didn´t help me that much so that´s why I´m posting this.

I´m getting a Bad Parcelable exception everytime I try to recover information from a parcel. Here's my class code.

```
public class Persona implements Parcelable {

private String nombre,email,tel;

public Persona() {
    nombre = "";
    email = "";
    tel = "";
}

public Persona(String nombre, String email, String tel) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.email = email;
    this.tel = tel;
}

public Persona(Parcel p){
    setNombre(p.readString());
    setEmail(p.readString());
    setTel(p.readString());
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getTel() {
    return tel;
}

public void setTel(String tel) {
    this.tel = tel;
}

@Override 
public String toString() {  
  return this.getNombre() + " " + this.getEmail() + " " + this.getTel();
}

public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel des, int flags) {

    des.writeString(getNombre());
    des.writeString(getEmail());
    des.writeString(getTel());

}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Persona> creator = new Creator<Persona>() {

    public Persona createFromParcel(Parcel source) {

        return new Persona(source);
    }

    public Persona[] newArray(int size) {

        return new Persona[size];
    }

};
```

}

And my activity code (this activity retrieves an intent that carries an ArrayList of the type I just specified)

```
public class Contacts extends Activity {

private ArrayAdapter<String> names;
private Intent intent;
private ArrayList<String>nameList;
private ListView list;

public Contacts() {
    intent = new Intent();
    nameList = new ArrayList<String>();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.contacts);
    setIntent(getIntent());
    iterateContacts();
    names = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getNameList());
    getList().setAdapter(getNames());
}

public void iterateContacts(){

    ArrayList<Persona> aux = GetIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("contactList");

    for(int i = 0; i<aux.size(); i++){

        String name = aux.get(i).getNombre();
        getNameList().add(name);
    }
}

public ArrayAdapter<String> getNames() {
    return names;
}

public void setNames(ArrayAdapter<String> names) {
    this.names = names;
}

public Intent GetIntent() {
    return intent;
}

public void setIntent(Intent intent) {
    this.intent = intent;
}

public ArrayList<String> getNameList() {
    return nameList;
}

public void setNameList(ArrayList<String> nameList) {
    this.nameList = nameList;
}

public ListView getList() {
    return list;
}

public void setList(ListView list) {
    this.list = list;
}
```

}

LOGCAT:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(861): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-10 02:39:10.738: E/AndroidRuntime(861): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.take2/com.take2.Contacts}: android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcelable protocol requires a Parcelable.Creator object called  CREATOR on class com.take2.Persona
09-10 02:39:10.738: E/AndroidRuntime(861):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
09-10 02:39:10.738: E/AndroidRuntime(861):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
09-10 02:39:10.738: E/AndroidRuntime(861):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
09-10 02:39:10.738: E/AndroidRuntime(861):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
09-10 02:39:10.738: E/AndroidRuntime(861):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-10 02:39:10.738: E/AndroidRuntime(861):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-10 02:39:10.738: E/AndroidRuntime(861):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
09-10 02:39:10.738: E/AndroidRuntime(861):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-10 02:39:10.738: E/AndroidRuntime(861):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-10 02:39:10.738: E/AndroidRuntime(861):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-10 02:39:10.738: E/AndroidRuntime(861):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-10 02:39:10.738: E/AndroidRuntime(861):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-10 02:39:10.738: E/AndroidRuntime(861):  at com.take2.Contacts.onCreate(Contacts.java:28)
09-10 02:39:10.738: E/AndroidRuntime(861):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
09-10 02:39:10.738: E/AndroidRuntime(861):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
```

Comment: post the log cat. Or check which line gives the Exception

Comment: It is recomended not to say "thanks in advance" or "any help apreciated". SO is about concrete questions, not formal letters. You will get more attention if you respect that in the future.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change this:

```
public static final Parcelable.Creator<Persona> creator = new Creator<Persona>() {
```

To this:

```
public static final Parcelable.Creator<Persona> CREATOR = new Creator<Persona>() {
```

Edit:

Also looks like your getList() returns null since it wasnt set before you do this at the end of onCreate:

```
getList().setAdapter(getNames());
```

Dont see were you initialize it, might this be the cause?

Comment: I added something, hope thats helping out!

Comment: Thanks a lot! What a silly mistake! I wasn´t using the findViewById method in order to init the ListView control! Now it works. Thanks again

Comment: Thank you. Its working after adding public static final Parcelable.Creator<Persona> CREATOR = new Creator<Persona>() {