# My Android service does not start

Tags: android, android-intent, service, android-manifest

My service does not start.

I used the following `onCreate` method within my service:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        wsConnection = new WSConnection();
        handler = new Handler();
        Bundle b = savedInstanceState;
        this.dbManager = b.getParcelable("object");

        super.onCreate();
        Log.i("prova","servizio attivato");
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask(){
            public void run(){


                FindPendingData();
            }

        };
        timer = new Timer();
        //timer.schedule(task, cal.getTime());
        timer.schedule(task, 0, 30000);
    }
```

while, the following code starts my service:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, myService.class);
        intent.putExtra("object", myObject);
        startService(intent);
```

object extends `Object` and implements `Parcelable`

I also declare in the Manifest:

```
<service android:name="myPackage.myService" />
```

Any idea Where the problem may be?

**EDIT**: I tried removing the Bundle parameter and now the service starts! But I don't understand why! Someone can help me?

Comment: any, like, error or something ?

Comment: you'd rather use onStartCommand, that's where startService ends

Comment: @njzk2 no error. I always use this code for starting service and usually this works good.

Comment: How do you know that this does not work?

Comment: @Mike, I tried putting Log.i() in run() method, but nothing is printed

Comment: @Joseph82 try putting it in the onCreate, just to make sure that the TimerTask isn't the issue

Comment: @Mike, even in onCreate the Log.i does not produce nothing.
I tried also, without passing any parameters.

Answer (score 0):

use [onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29) or [onStart()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStart%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) instead of onCreate of Service for getting Intent data as:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      // get intent data here
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

as in comment OP says :

> no error. I always use this code for starting service and usually
>   this works good

but if we see in doc [onCreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onCreate%28%29)   not take any parameter if you are overriding it

Comment: You are right, my previous code does not include paramaters to pass.

Comment: I tried putting the code for getting intent in onStartCommand but this error occur: Parcelable protocol requires a Parcelable.
I use this code:
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
       // get intent data here
  Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
  this.dbManager = b.getParcelable("object");
     return START_STICKY;
 }

Comment: @Joseph82 : from which class you are creating myObject instance?

Comment: @Joseph82 : change `this.dbManager = b.getParcelable("object"); ` to  `myObject = b.getParcelable("object"); `

Comment: @Joseph82 : and also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12348627/bad-parcelable-exception) post to solve next issue